# How to get this output using? Javascript to remove consecutive character is a given string to be same?(Bomber algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How to get this output using? Javascript to remove consecutive character is a given string to be same?(Bomber algorithm)
example:
input 1: aabcccdee
aabcccdee->bcccdee->bdee->bd
output1: bd

input2:  abcdeedcbfgf
abcdeedcbfgf->eeabcddcbfgf->abcddcbfgf->abccbfgf->abbfgf->afgf
output2: afgf

Comment: Are you sure that the ouput2 is `afgf`? Isn't it `ag`??

Comment: yeah the output is afgf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the character with the character at the index before and after and return a new string. Repeat while changing.

```js
function b(s) {
    var t;

    do {
        t = s;
        s = t.split('').filter(function (a, i, aa) {
            return a !== aa[i - 1] && a !== aa[i + 1];
        }).join('');
    } while (s !== t);
    return s;
}

console.log(b('aabcccdee'));
console.log(b('abcdeedcbfgf'));
```

Comment: This introduced me to the split -> filter -> join  way of solving such problems. Very cleanly done indeed!

Comment: Hey what if I want to remove only the 3 consecutive characters rather than the current all duplicate types . What changes can I make? For ex: "aaabbc" should be "bbc"

Comment: @HebleV, then use just a regular expression for replacing `/(.)\1{2}/g`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But how without Regex ?

Comment: @HebleV, maybe you ask a new question ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply another take from head of `a` and concatenate to tail of `b` problem very suitable for tail code optimized recursive invocations or a while loop approach.

My solution would be;

```js
function reduceString(a, b = "",c = 0){
  if (!a.length) return c ? b.slice(0,-c-1) : b;
  b[b.length-1] === a[0] ? (c++, b += a[0], a = a.slice(1))
                         : c ? (b = b.slice(0,-c-1), c = 0)
                             : (b += a[0], a = a.slice(1));
  return reduceString(a,b,c);
}

var myArr = "aabcccdee",
   result = reduceString(myArr);
console.log(result);
console.log(reduceString("abcdeedcbfgf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalString = "";
var bombIt = function(currentString){
     var currentArray = currentString.split('');
     var counter = 1;
     var recurAgain = false;
     var currentString = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++){
        recurAgain = false;
        if(currentArray[i] == currentArray[i+1]){
            counter++
            continue;
        }
        if(counter > 2){
            recurAgain = true;
            currentArray.splice(i+1-counter,counter);
            counter = 1;
            break;
        }else{
            counter = 1;
        }
     }
     if(recurAgain){
        bombIt(currentArray.join(''));
     }else{
        finalString = currentArray.join('');
     }
}; 
bombIt("aabbbcceeecfffa");
```

Comment: Here i am checking for three or more consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the solution here , They have explained 2 ways http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/

A simple approach using stack , I have provided a pseudo code complexity O(n)

```
str = abccbfgf
Stack s;
counter = 0
bombFlag = false
while(counter < str.length){
char = str.index(counter);
 if(s.isEmpty){
    push( {char,1 })
 }else{
    top = s.peek;
    if(top.val == char )
        ctr = top.counter+1;
        push( {char,ctr })
        if(ctr >= 2){
            bombFlag = true;
        }
    else{
        if(bombFlag){
        loopCtr = top.counter;
        bombFlag = false
        (loopCtr > 0)
         s.pop()
         loopCtr--; 
        }
        push( {char,1 })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function b(s) 
{
var t;
do {t = s;s = t.split('').filter(function (a, i, aa) {
     if(i==0) return a;
     else
     return a !== aa[i - 1] && a !== aa[i + 1];}).join('');} while (s !== t); 
     return s;
}
console.log(b("abbabbac"));
console.log(b('aabcccdee'));
console.log(b('abcdeedcbfgf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is simple solution in java for given question:-**

```
import java.io.*;


    public class Arr {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            InputStreamReader r =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

            //char[] ab= {'a','b','b','c','c','d','e','e','d'};
            String a=br.readLine();
            int i=0,j=0,k;
            char[] ab= a.toCharArray();
            char[] c = new char[ab.length];
            char[] d= new char[ab.length];

            for(k=1;k<ab.length-1;k++)
            {
                if(ab[k]==ab[k-1] && ab[k]!='\0')
                {
                for (i=1;i<ab.length;i++)
                {
                    if(ab[i]!=ab[i-1])
                    {
                            c[j]=ab[i-1];
                            j++;
                            if(i==ab.length-1)
                            {

                                c[j]=ab[i];
                                j++;
                            }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        i=i+1;
                            if(i==ab.length-1)    
                            {
                                c[j]=ab[i];
                                j++;
                            }
                    }
                }
                ab=c;
                c=d;
                k=0;
                j=0;
                }
            }

                for(j=0;j<ab.length;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(ab[j]);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Above is the simple logic code for printing output such as: aabcccdee aabcccdee->bcccdee->bdee->bd

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BoomberAlogrithm {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcccbda";
    int size = s.length();
    BoomberAlogrithm boom = new BoomberAlogrithm();
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {

            if (a[i] != a[j]) {
                if (c > 0) {
                    while (c + 1 > 0) {
                        for (int k = i; k < size - 1; k++) {
                            a[k] = a[k + 1];

                        }
                        size--;
                        c--;
                    }
                    i = 0;
                    c = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                c++;
            }

        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}

}
```